# Gradient of a homogenous function - proof with a help function ; Unsure about a derivative and about using the multidimensional chain rule

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification

Let $k$ be an integer. A function $f : \mathbb{R^n} \to \mathbb{R}$ is called *homogenous* of degree $k$ if $f(\lambda x) = \lambda^k f(x)$ for all $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ and $x \in \mathbb{R^n}$. Prove that if $f$ is homogenous of degree $k$ then $x \cdot \nabla f(x) = kf(x)$.

Task: Prove this statement using the function $g:\mathbb{R}^+\rightarrow \mathbb{R}, \lambda \mapsto f(\lambda x)$ for a fixed $x\in \mathbb{R^n}$

Proof: Let $x\in \mathbb{R^n}$ be arbitrary but fixed.

i) $g'(\lambda)=\frac{d}{d\lambda}f(\lambda x)=\frac{d}{d\lambda}(\lambda^kf(x))=k \lambda^{k-1}f(x)$
$\Rightarrow g'(1)=kf(x)$

ii) $g'(\lambda)=\frac{d}{d\lambda}f(\lambda x)=x\cdot f'(\lambda x)\Rightarrow g'(1)=x\cdot f'(x)$

$(i),(ii)\Rightarrow g'(1)=x\cdot f'(x)=kf(x)$ **almost** **q.e.d.**

I have problems with $\frac{d}{d\lambda}f(\lambda x)=x\cdot f'(\lambda x)$ in (ii) because it should probably be $\frac{d}{d\lambda}f(\lambda x)=x\cdot \nabla f(\lambda x)$ but I cannot justify it.
Is the notation $g'(\lambda)=\frac{d}{d\lambda}f(\lambda x)$   wrong? I used this notation  because $g$ is a onedimensional function.

I tried to use the multivariable chain rule with
$h:\mathbb{R}^+\rightarrow \mathbb{R^n}, \lambda \mapsto \lambda x$

$g(\lambda)=f(h(\lambda))\Rightarrow g'(\lambda)=Dg(\lambda)=D(f\circ h)(\lambda)=Df(\lambda x)\cdot Dh(\lambda)=\nabla f(\lambda x)\cdot h'(\lambda)=\nabla f(\lambda x)\cdot x= x\cdot \nabla f(\lambda x)=0$
because $\nabla f(\lambda x)=0$ for a fixed $x$.

Apart from the point mentioned, is the proof correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a mistake with the chain rule in point $(ii)$; you shoud have :
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\lambda}f(\lambda x) = \nabla f(\lambda x) \cdot \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\lambda}(\lambda x) = x \cdot \nabla f(\lambda x)
$$
because $f$ is a scalar field (operating on $\mathbb{R}^n$) and not a mere function. The conclusion is thus :
$$
g'(\lambda) = k\lambda^{k-1}f(\lambda x) = x \cdot \nabla f(\lambda x)
$$
which gives the desired relation when evaluating at $\lambda = 1$.